# Concept of eigenvector restricted to nonnegative entries

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvector

Let $X\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ be a positive semidefinite matrix. The leading eigenvector $v\in \mathbb{R}^n$ of $X$ is the solution to the problem

$\arg \max_{v:\lVert v\rVert_2=1} \lambda\quad$ such that $\quad Xv=\lambda v$  $\qquad$ **(P1)**

Is there a similar thing for $v\in\mathbb{R}_+^{n}$ (i.e., nonnegative $v$)? In particular, I am looking for the solution to the following problem:

$\arg \max_{v\geq 0,\lVert v\rVert_2=1} \lambda\quad$ such that $\quad (Xv)_+=\lambda v$  $\qquad$ **(P2)**

(here $(\cdot)_+$ denotes the operator that makes the $-ve$ entries of a vector zero, i.e. $(v)_+ = \max(v,0)$)

Will the fixed point iteration give me the solution?

If the entries of matrix $X$ are non-negative, we know that the solution to both problems P1 and P2 is same and is give by the leading eigenvector of $X$, but I am interested in the general case where entires of $X$ can be negative.

Comment: Look at http://arxiv.org/pdf/0710.1313.pdf, this might help

Comment: Also related: http://arxiv.org/pdf/1307.3109.pdf